# NTP service does not seen in ps aux

Tags: sync, services, ntp

On a linux based system I install ntp service to sync the date/time and I do not see a sync.

I check if the service was running with "systemctl status ntp" and then "ps aux"

```
systemctl status ntp
● ntp.service - LSB: Start NTP daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/ntp)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 1970-01-09 02:05:38 UTC; 36min ago
  Process: 14186 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/ntp stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16174 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/ntp start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 09 02:05:38 pegase2-mosiwind systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start NTP daemon.
Jan 09 02:05:38 pegase2-mosiwind ntpd[16181]: proto: precision = 30.518 usec
Jan 09 02:05:38 pegase2-mosiwind ntpd[16181]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123
Jan 09 02:05:38 pegase2-mosiwind ntpd[16181]: Listen and drop on 1 v6wildcard :: UDP 123
Jan 09 02:05:38 pegase2-mosiwind ntpd[16181]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
Jan 09 02:05:38 pegase2-mosiwind ntpd[16181]: Listen normally on 3 eth0 192.168.126.10 UDP 123
Jan 09 02:05:38 pegase2-mosiwind ntpd[16181]: Listen normally on 4 lo ::1 UDP 123
Jan 09 02:05:38 pegase2-mosiwind ntpd[16181]: Listen normally on 5 eth0 fe80::250:c2ff:fe43:b419 UDP 123
Jan 09 02:05:38 pegase2-mosiwind ntpd[16181]: peers refreshed
Jan 09 02:05:38 pegase2-mosiwind ntpd[16181]: Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates
```

And the ps aux command

```
ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.7   5344  3812 ?        Ss   Jan01   4:32 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01   0:01 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01   3:49 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7  0.4  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01  53:48 [rcu_sched]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01   0:00 [migration/0]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [netns]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [perf]
root        73  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [writeback]
root       306  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [crypto]
root       307  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       309  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [kblockd]
root       482  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [rpciod]

root       501  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01   0:00 [kswapd0]
root       502  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [vmstat]
root       503  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root       504  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [nfsiod]
root       559  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       560  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       561  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       562  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       563  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       564  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       565  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       566  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       567  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       568  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       569  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       570  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       571  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       572  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       573  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       574  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       608  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       611  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       614  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       617  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       620  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       623  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       626  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       629  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       644  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       649  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       654  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       659  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       664  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       670  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01   1:08 [spi1]
root       673  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01   0:00 [spi2]
root       675  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01   0:00 [spi3]
root       677  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01   0:00 [spi4]
root       730  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       774  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [deferwq]
root       776  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01   0:00 [irq/72-48070000]
root       784  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01   0:00 [irq/23-TWL4030-]
root       840  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01  32:51 [irq/77-48060000]
root       861  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [bioset]
root       862  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01   4:46 [mmcqd/0]
root       870  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:24 [kworker/0:1H]
root       871  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01   1:33 [jbd2/mmcblk0p2-]
root       872  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root       876  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
root      1414  0.0  0.6   8152  3148 ?        Ss   Jan01   7:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root      1599  0.0  0.5  10732  2728 ?        Ss   Jan01   0:02 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
root      1707  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [cfg80211]
root      1712  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jan01   0:00 [wl12xx_wq]
root      1737  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01   0:00 [irq/170-wl18xx]
root      1828  0.0  0.4   3472  2012 ?        Ss   Jan01   0:03 /usr/sbin/cron -f
root      1835  0.0  0.8   7928  4404 ?        Ss   Jan01   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root      1842  2.9  1.7  82548  8600 ?        Ssl  Jan01 346:51 /usr/bin/Zeus
root      1856  0.0  0.4   3372  2088 ?        Ss   Jan01   0:56 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
message+  1861  0.0  0.6   5588  3056 ?        Ss   Jan01   1:47 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
root      1891  0.0  0.7  31368  3608 ?        Ssl  Jan01   1:38 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
root      1920  0.0  0.3   2428  1576 tty1     Ss+  Jan01   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
root      1927  0.0  0.3   2248  1524 ttyO2    Ss+  Jan01   0:00 /sbin/agetty --keep-baud 115200 38400 9600 ttyO2 vt102
root      1939  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan01   0:00 [irq/338-4902000]
root      1952  0.0  1.2   8688  6108 ?        Ss   Jan01   0:00 dhclient -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases eth0
root      3541  0.0  0.4   3436  2484 ?        Ss   00:44   0:00 /bin/bash /etc/SAGE_launcher.sh
root      3585  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    00:44   0:05 [irq_dealer]
root      3602  0.0  0.5   5620  2704 ?        S    00:44   0:00 sudo sage
root      3606  4.7  5.1 187188 25748 ?        Sl   00:44   4:38 sage
root     12328  0.6  0.0      0     0 ?        S    01:40   0:17 [kworker/u2:3]
root     14378  0.7  0.0      0     0 ?        S    01:54   0:13 [kworker/u2:1]
root     15070  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    01:58   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
root     16225  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    02:05   0:00 [kworker/0:2]
root     17392  1.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    02:13   0:05 [kworker/u2:2]
root     18361  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    02:20   0:00 [kworker/u2:0]
root     18377  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    02:20   0:00 [kworker/0:1]
root     18623  2.5  0.9  11416  4904 ?        Ss   02:21   0:00 sshd: pegase [priv] 
pegase   18633  1.0  0.7  11416  3508 ?        S    02:21   0:00 sshd: pegase@pts/0  
pegase   18637  0.5  0.5   3632  2848 pts/0    Ss   02:21   0:00 -bash
root     18650  6.0  0.5   4592  2584 pts/0    S    02:21   0:00 sudo su
root     18660  4.0  0.4   4424  2340 pts/0    S    02:21   0:00 su
root     18665  3.0  0.5   3620  2844 pts/0    S    02:21   0:00 bash
root     18670  0.0  0.3   3096  1692 pts/0    R+   02:21   0:00 ps aux
```

I don't get why the service is shown "Loaded" and "Active" but does not appear in the list of the processes.

On other hand, I stop the ntp service with "systemctl stop ntp" and I tried to change the time with the "date" command, the date changes but goes back to "1970" right after

Comment: Try `sudo ps -aux | grep -i ntp`

Comment: Except for the command itself, it does not return any other process